# Shifting digits

Tags: code-golf, number

Given a string representing a number and the base that number is in, shift each positional value upward, wrapping back to zero if the value cannot increase. You will never be provided invalid input, nor a base larger than 36.

For example, you may be provided `['5f6', '16']`, which represents the number 1526 in base 16. The expected output in that case would be `'607'` (1543 in base 16).

#### Input

- program: separate lines from STDIN: `'5f6\n16'`
- function: a tuple or array: `f(['5f6', '16'])` or `f(['5f6', 16])`
- function: two arguments `f('5f6', '16')` or `f('5f6', 16)`

#### Output

- program: to STDOUT: `607`
- function: returned as a string: `'607'`

#### Test cases

```
['5f6', '16']
'607'

['abc', '36']
'bcd'

['1', '1'] or ['0', '1']
'1' or '0'

['9540', '10']
'0651' or '651'

['001', '2']
'110'
```

Comment: Is the input format that strict, or can I take the input for my program as, say, `"5f6"\n16`?

Comment: @ETHproductions: That would be acceptable.

Comment: What is the answer for `['999', '10']`?

Comment: @tsh: That would be `'000'`

Comment: Are we allowed to use uppercase letters instead of lowercase letters? Also do we have to handle base 1?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman: Uppercase and lowercase are both acceptable. Base 1 is also an acceptable input.

Comment: This isn't shifting, this is *incrementing* each digit.  i.e. add-without-carry of `1111111111...` in whatever base.

Comment: You haven't specified what base 1 input will look like. Since unary isn't a positional number system I wouldn't require supporting it if I were you, but if you do you should specify what digit is used.

Comment: @Jakob: I've add some test cases; including a case for base 1.

Comment: Is it okay if we use `0` for base `1` (Third test case would be `[0,1]=>1`)? My case: `n` is never used in base `n`, since there's no `2` in binary, `3` in ternary, etc.

Comment: @Zacharý: Sure, that's acceptable. I'll modify that test case.

Answer (score 7):

## [Paradoc](https://github.com/betaveros/paradoc) (v0.2.10), 10 bytes (CP-1252)

```
DaÅ+<:<oTr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsSkzJT/6vZOpmpqRgaPbfJfFwq7aNlU1@SNH//wA)

Takes the string and the base as an integer from the stack, results in a string on the stack.

Whoops, I don't know why I don't have a `0-9A-Z` constant yet. It would shave two bytes. (Assumes input is uppercase; for lowercase replace `Å` with `La`.)

Explanation:

```
Da         .. Push the digit alphabet
  Å        .. Push the uppercase alphabet
   +       .. Concatenate them
    <      .. Take the slice of the first (base) characters
     :     .. Duplicate
      <o   .. Left-rotate by one
        Tr .. Translate through the last two strings
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
®nV Ä sV Ì
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rm5WIMQgc1YgzA==&input=IjVmNiIgMTY=)

The 3-byters `nV`  and `sV`  are rather annoying...

#### Explanation

```
 ®   nV Ä  sV Ì     
UmZ{ZnV +1 sV gJ}   Ungolfed
                    Implicit: U = input string, V = base
UmZ{            }   Map each char in Z to
    ZnV               Z converted from base V to decimal,
        +1            plus 1,
           sV         converted back to base V,
              gJ      and shortened to only the last char. (J = -1)
                    Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>77</s> <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```python
lambda s,m:''.join(chr(c+[48,55][c>9])for c in[-~int(x,m)%m for x in s])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ9dKXV0vKz8zTyM5o0gjWTvaxELH1DQ2OtnOMlYzLb9IIVkhMy9aty4zr0SjQidXUzVXASRaARRVKI7V/F9QBJRRSNNQN02zVNcxNNPkQoiYm6nrWCAJpFUBlRgDlfwHAA)

Takes a string and an int base. Works up to base 36.

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFYJ9dKXV0vKz8zTyM5o0hDty4zr0SjQidXUzVX28RC21wLRcjOUlMzLb9IoUIhM0@hWPN/QRFQTiFNQ900zVJdx9BMkwshYm6mrmOBJJBWBVRiDFTyHwA)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 57 bytes

```
(a,b)=>a.replace(/./g,v=>(-~parseInt(v,b)%b).toString(b))
```

Comment: Save a byte with currying: `a=>b=>`

Comment: This doesn't function with base 1

Comment: @Bálint I wouldn't expect any solution to work with base 1...

Comment: @ETHproductions Quoting one of the comments from OP "Base 1 is also an acceptable input"

Comment: @Bálint: Acceptable, not required. Also, comments do not a spec make.

Comment: @Shaggy But is currying valid for this question?

Comment: @Bálint what does base 1 mean? input some zeroes and output them as is?

Comment: @tsh currying is valid for every question. And yes. See the Jelly answer

Comment: Why wouldn't it be valid? Currying is only (currently) "illegal" if you're not passing an argument to the second function. i.e., `f(a)(b)` is OK but `f(a)()` isn't (currently).

Comment: @Shaggy But the question require "from STDIN", or "input a pair", or "input with two paramter". And the requirement from question override the default one.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

3 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan.

```
ØBiÐ€⁸%⁹‘ịØB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDKfMwxMeNa151LhD9VHjzkcNMx7u7gaK/v//X8nUzUzpv6EZAA)

### How it works

```
ØBiÐ€⁸%⁹‘ịØB
ØB           "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
  iÐ€⁸       index of each in first input
      %⁹     modulo the second input
        ‘    increase by 1
         ị   index into
          ØB "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Comment: `ØBiÐ€⁸%⁹‘ịØB` for 12 bytes (uppercase acceptable)

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Guess you wish Jelly had [builtins for string <-> number base conversions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141433/55550), though, huh? Also, can you please explain how this works (mainly the order in which it's parsed)?

Comment: @Zacharý added.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <del>11</del> 10 bytes

```
.rE<+jkUTG
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.rE%3C%2BjkUTG&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=36%0A%22abc%22%0A16%0A%225f6%22%0A2%0A%221101%22%0A1%0A%22000%22&debug=0&input_size=2)

Thanks to Mr. XCoder for saving 1 byte!

We use `.r` to cyclically rotate over the alphabet of the given base. We build that using `G` as the built in alphabet, and then a range of numbers, and slicing off the excess.

Comment: The notification I got of your answer said "Pyth, 0 bytes" and I almost did a spit take! 11 bytes is still great, though. :-)

Comment: @ZachGates Haha, that was caused by me copying an empty TIO body link and then filling it out to save me the trouble of typesetting the answer. Unfortunately I forgot to change the byte count, but the edit that happened in the grace period doesn't get reflected in the notification I think. I hope I didn't startle you too much :P

Comment: [10 bytes](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.rE%3C%2BjkUTG&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=36%0A%22abc%22%0A16%0A%225f6%22%0A2%0A%221101%22%0A1%0A%22000%22&debug=0&input_size=2) (`.rE<+jkUTG`). I have absolutely no idea why you have a `J` in there, as you only use it once.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Whoa, I guess that's what golfing at 1am does to someone.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>75</s> <s>74</s> 65 bytes

*Thanks to @tsh for saving 9 bytes!*

```
f(n,b)char*n;{for(;*n;++n)*n=*n-b-(b>10?86:47)?*n-57?*n+1:97:48;}
```

Modifies the input string directly.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7LCoMwEEX3foW4yviAxFeMofVDShcaSOuiqRi7qOK3pynU0kLAzXCZezgzIrkIYYxEKu5AXNsxVHyR9xFxG6JIQagOoUq6BHVHgpuqrHMKjd0U1M6I1IzWecVX06vJv7W9QuAt3lvk61OWnrmnp1EMT6TjoJBlAFzaSErgw2PSSMM/wHYAuhkqZy/nTZC5BQzPOwD7voCdACEYE0w@UOpm0u3IT72aFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
ö¹в>¹%¹β¹B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//8O2wrnQsj7CuSXCuc6ywrlC//8xNgo1RjY)

Comment: This seems pretty fitting, as 05AB1E came from `base`. Also, can you add an explanation of what all those b's mean?

Comment: @Zacharý They're all base stuff including the `ö` :p

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 59 bytes

```hs
map.(%)
b%c|mod(fromEnum c-b)39==8='0'
_%'9'='a'
_%c=succ c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu7DoIwFADQna@4IZLCgEERhOGOfoGriSkXCkgLlVJf8dutup3ldNwMjZRO4MkprtdhEHlVQG811aGYJ3UYrQKKqygtEQtkCfPOASsZMv4XobFEQL/bj4Cg7XJcZliBgDQHP9ls012W74uSV1Q3ou36yyDVOOnrbBZ7uz@eL999SEjeGheT1l8) Usage: `map.(%) $ 16 "5f6"` yields `"607"`.

**Edit:** -1 byte thanks to nimi, -5 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen.

Comment: A [multiline definition of %](https://tio.run/##DcyxCoMwEIDh3ac4peEiYmyHCg73FB1VSjxMK40SjG599qa3/XzD/7bxM3ufHA1ptcFoVWaT4i8T6R4bNAY7HKuqRys9lnk@EV4xeypxEpRiiiczsAyWDQjCeTyOHS7g4NZCcXddkX7svH3FVHMIfw) saves a byte.

Comment: @nimi Thanks! It's always nicer to have powers of 2 as byte count.

Comment: A shorter test for the second line: `mod(fromEnum c-b)39==8`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks! Switching to upper-case letters even saves another byte.

Comment: Um you cannot use upper-case letters for this trick - the modulus needs to be larger than the highest base supported, otherwise it gives false positives.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

## [MY](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language), 8 [bytes](https://bitbucket.org/zacharyjtaylor/my-language/src/ca5cdd70d46e932ed06f4a150b9a6c81de75be5d/codepage.txt?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

```
αωP‘%pέ←
```

I definitely made the right choice adding the basify (`P`) and stringify (`p`) atoms!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9tef//zrHPiVDigJglcM6t4oaQ////JzVGNif/MTY)

### How it works, along with a reason for the codepoint

- `α`, push the second command line argument (taken from APL, but it's the greek symbol instead of the APL one)
- `ω`, push the first command line argument (also taken from APL)
- `P`, pop `n`; push n basified (`0`-`Z` => `0`-`35`, `b` flipped is `p`)
- `‘`, pop `n`; push `n + 1` (vectorizes ["vecifies" in MY], taken from jelly)
- `%`, pop `a`; pop `b`; push `a%b` (vecifies, do I really need to give this to you?)
- `p`, pop `n`; push `n` stringified (`0`-`35` => `0`-`Z`, vecifies, same origin as `P`)
- `έ`, pop `n`; push `"".join(n)` (`ε` is the **e**mpty string, and just put an accent mark over it)
- `←`, pop `n`; output `n` with no newline. (Pushing it away from the stack to STDOUT)

**THIS** is what MY was meant for!

Comment: MY is winning! Holy crap!

Comment: I can't believe MY is outgolfing the language named after base!

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 83 bytes

```php
while(($c=$argv[1][$i++])>'')echo base_convert(intval($c,$b=$argv[2])+1,10,$b)[-1];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkyzMyc1I1NFSSbVUSi9LLog1jo1UytbVjNe3U1TVTkzPyFZISi1Pjk/PzylKLSjQy80rKEnOAynVUkqA6jGI1tQ11DA2AIprRuoax1v///zdNM/tvaAYA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, <s>81</s> <s>78</s> <s>74</s> <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```python
import string
lambda a,b:''.join(string.printable[-~int(i,b)%b]for i in a)if b>1else a
```

Alternatively:

```python
lambda a,b:''.join(__import__('string').printable[-~int(i,b)%b]for i in a)if b>1else a
```

Comment: `f('6f3', '32')` get wrong output `'7164'`

Comment: @tsh: Absolutely right. Fixed.

Comment: `(x+1)%y` -> `-~x%y`,

Comment: @tsh: Beat me to it. I was trying to figure out that bit flip right now. Thanks :-)

Comment: What is `[:b]` used?

Comment: @tsh: I replaced `[:36]` with `[:b]` to drop a byte. Only the first `b` characters of `string.printable` are relevant to a given base.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64920/discussion-between-tsh-and-zach-gates).

Comment: You can remove the space between `1` and `else`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 62 bytes

```
(h=#2;""<>ToString/@(Mod[#~FromDigits~h+1,h]&/@Characters@#))&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvtfI8NW2chaScnGLiQ/uKQoMy9d30HDNz8lWrnOrSg/1yUzPbOkuC5D21AnI1ZN38E5I7EoMbkktajYQVlTU@1/AFBHiYJDWrSSaZqZko6hWez//wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>53</s> 59 bytes

```ruby
->n,b{b<2?n:n.chars.map{|c|(c.to_i(b)+1).to_s(b)[-1]}.join}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v1jBVkHXLk8nqTrJxsg@zypPLzkjsahYLzexoLomuUYjWa8kPz5TI0lT21ATxCwGMqN1DWNr9bLyM/NqubgKSkuKFYr1khNzcjTUE5OS1XUUDI01UYVN08xAwmZowgZAABLX/P8fAA)

Originally 6 bytes less, but Ruby doesn't like using a base of 1.

Could save 5 bytes by removing `.join` if the output did not need to be a string.

Comment: You can remove two spaces from the start.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
≔…⁺⪫ＥχＩιωβＮθＦＳ§θ⁺¹⌕θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLCoMwFET3fsVd3kAKzUI3rqRQUGgR@gXRqA2kieZh@/fp1cXAnDkw41v60UmTcxOCXiw@nFHYmxSwc5pQriiuHG4yRNSMcfhSBkpr1xSf6TNMHo99Y3UxOw94ilf02i4koKcSsYmtVdMPNw7nueBw11YdTK@M1TmLqijnKl928wc) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 2 bytes by using `CycleChop` instead of `Slice`. Explanation:

```
    Ｅχ                  Loop over the digits
      Ｉι                Cast to string
   ⪫    ω               Join together
  ⁺      β              Append the lowercase letters
          Ｎ             First input as a number
 …                      Take `n` characters from the start
≔          θ            Assign to variable `q`
            ＦＳ          Loop over the characters in the second input
                  ⌕θι   Find the character index in `q`
                ⁺¹      Plus 1
              §θ        Cyclically index in `q`
                        Implicitly print
```

Note: Later versions of Charcoal reduce this to 20 bytes: `≔…⁺⪫ＥχＩιωβＮθＦＳ§θ⊕⌕θι`

Comment: [use the AST to help explain when the deverbosifier is out of order :P](https://tio.run/##AU8AsP9jaGFyY29hbP//4omU4pyC4oG64qqr77ylz4fvvKnOuc@JzrLigbDvvK7Cuc6477ym77yzwqfOuOKBusK54oyVzrjOuf//MTYKNWY2/y1h) (also yeah i came across that bug too whoops)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 87 bytes

```
list(,$a,$b)=$argv;for(;$c=intval($a{$i++},$b);)echo$b>1?base_convert(++$c%$b,10,$b):1;
```

Run with `-r` like this:

```
php -r "list(,$a,$b)=$argv;for(;$c=intval($a{$i++},$b);)echo$b>1?base_convert(++$c%$b,10,$b):1;" xyz 36
```

Works with bases 1 to 36, inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 71 bytes

```bash
b=({0..9} {a..z})
for c in `fold -w1<<<$1`;{ echo -n ${b[-~$2#$c%$2]};}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQfacYaIJaKH1WkZ0kgtK@GEoFCYldfXpPjvdGJNvU55zXAfzI@RuyaLEXKNgNDIs9JmCuEEJgMTQeZrVZYAbQy459WMaoEiz70AQiWietjXvMqRVV1Q8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-lF`, <s>61</s> 53 bytes

```perl
$l=(0..9,a..z,aa)[<>];say map{++$_;/$l/?0:s/10/a/r}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lx1bDQE/PUidRT69KJzFRM9rGLta6OLFSITexoFpbWyXeWl8lR9/ewKpY39BAP1G/qNbB7f9/A0MjYxNTM3MLy8Sk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy8/ILCouKS0rLyisoqLmOzf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5rgBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╕W─░ì]
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b857c4b08d5d&i=5f6%0A16%0A%0Aabc%0A36%0A%0A1%0A1%0A%0A9540%0A10%0A%0A001%0A2&a=1&m=1)

#### Procedure:

1. Push constant "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
2. Get and eval base, now two spots down the stack
3. Truncate digit string to specified count.
4. "Ring" translate using remaining characters.  This maps each character to the next, wrapping around to "0" at the end.